# scroll to top button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

i have div.triangle on my page at opacity 0
i want it to fade into opacity .95 once the bottom of the page is hit
then after that, i want it to scroll to the top of $(".container") once $(".triangle") is clicked again
i have this so far, i think i've got most of it right other than the event?

> ```
>    <script type="text/javascript">
>       $(document).ready(function(){
>           $(".container").scroll(function(){
>               var currentPosition = $(document).scrollTop(); 
>               var totalHeight = $(document).offsetHeight;
>               var visibleHeight = $(document).clientHeight;
>                   if (visibleHeight + currentPosition >= totalHeight){
>                       $(".triangle").fadeTo("slow",.95);
>                   }
>           });
>           $(".triangle").click(function(){
>               $(".container").animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
>               $(".triangle").fadeTo("slow",0);
>           });
>       });
>    </script>
> ```

Comment: http://www.mattvarone.com/web-design/uitotop-jquery-plugin/ if you want to use a ready-to-use plugin, otherwise I'll add an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var bottom = ($(window).outerHeight() - $(window).height()) - 50; // 50 pixel to the bottom of the page; 
      $(window).scroll(function(){
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= bottom ) {
                  $(".triangle").fadeTo("slow",.95);
             } else {
                  $(".triangle").fadeOut("slow");
             }
      });

      $(".triangle").click(function(){
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
          $(".triangle").fadeOut("slow");
      });
  });
```